# API Redirect Flash Message, message not showing

Tags: php, laravel

I create an API that work like punch card machine. So when the GET API is requested, it should the result if access granted or access denied on login screen.

I'm running Laravel 5.7 with PHP 7.2. I already dump the session() variable, only cross ref token is shown.

api.php

```
Route::get('/{member_id}', 'ApiController@entry');
```

ApiController.php

```
public function entry($member_id)
{
    $user = User::where('member_id', $member_id)->first();

    if ($user == null)
        return redirect('login')->with('api_error','Access Denied');
    else
    {
        return redirect('login')->with('api_success','Entry Recorded');
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
@if (session('api_success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        {{ session('api_success') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if(session('api_error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        {{ session('api_error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Nothing is output after run the api link.

Extra Info : the login are scaffolding from php artisan make:auth

Comment: Perhaps I'm crazy, but are you missing the { after if ( $user == null ) ?

Comment: If this is a real api route declared in routes/api.php then it will not start the session. You should make it a web route since sessions and redirects are more relevant to a user journey rather than an interaction with an API